David Copperfield as non-boarding head boy in Dr Strong's school?
When David Copperfield begins attending Dr Strong's school, he boards with Mr Wickfield and the latter's daughter Agnes (pp. 208–209)1. The arrangement is intended to be temporary, but appears to endure throughout his time at the school: even when David is head boy, he speaks of Agnes moving about the house, indicating that they still live in the same residence (p. 251). This puzzles me. I'dn't've expected that a day scholar would be chosen as head boy of a boarding school. Presumably David would have been in school sometime in the late 1820s or early 1830s. Did some English boarding schools of the period allow a day scholar rather than a boarder to be chosen as head boy? It would be useful to know of real-life examples from that time, or at least to read contemporaneous school rules that allowed this. Assuming that this arrangement did in fact sometimes pertain, how common was it? And out of curiosity, does it still occasionally happen today?
      1 Dickens, Charles. David Copperfield. 1850. Introduction by David Gates. Notes by Nitin Govil. New York: Modern Library, 2000.

Why not? Day pupils aren't inferior beings; why shouldn't one of them  be chosen?

@KateBunting What gives you the impression I'm saying they shouldn't? I'm merely asking whether there's evidence that they on occasion were. If you're asking why I'dn't've expected their being chosen, that's a different question: I assumed, first, that boarders are more closely integrated into the life of the school (and indeed, from what little I know of day scholars vs boarders, this seems to be the case); and second, that a head boy would have specific responsibilities pertaining to the school's houses of residence.

When I said "why shouldn't they?", I meant "why did you consider it unusual or surprising?" I was a day-girl at a boarding school, but I don't remember that the head girl had to be a boarder.
